# Calling a PHP API from HTML Form?

Tags: php, html, forms, api, url

I've been developing iOS apps for a while now and have just started to get into designing my website. In one of my apps, I add data to my database by using:

```
let URL = NSURL(string: urlPath.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: URL!)

var response = ""
if let data = data{
        response = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
}
```

The `urlPath` would look something like: `http://mydomainname.com/folder/anotherFolder/theAPI.php?arg1=one&arg2=two&arg3=three` and so forth.

What I really want to be able to do is call that API.php file with all the arguments where each one (arg1=, arg2=, etc) is a field in a HTML form. I've found a couple of tutorials that deal with HTML forms and validating data, and now my form looks like:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
        <div id="formtext">Name</div>
        <input type="text" name="Name">
        <div id="formtext"><br>Email Address:</div>
        <input type="text" name="Email"><br>
        <div id="formtext"><br>Password</div>
        <input type="text" name="Password"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Apologies if the HTML is a little cringy, I'm not experienced enough to know what 'tidy'/conventional HTML code looks like and this is what I've managed to piece together from tutorials.
I also know that in the `action.php` you can get the values in the forms like: `$_POST['Name']`. I feel like I'm really close - I just can't find anywhere that will tell me how to call this api.

The closest I can get is:

```
$name = $_POST['Name']
$email = $_POST['Email']
$password = $_POST['Password']
$response = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/folder/api.php?Name=' . $name . '&Email=' . $email . '&Password=' . $password);
echo $response
```

If you're a php expert, again, sorry for butchering your code :)

(Oh, and the result just says there was an error on line 26 in the where clause - the API's fine because I tested it from my app).
Edit: Where clause used to be While Loop (sorry)

In conclusion, I'd greatly appreciate if someone showed me what to put in `action.php` (excluding verification - I'll get on to that later) and please do let me know if I'm doing anything ludicrously wrong.

Thanks :)

Comment: Except for not terminating your PHP lines with ; there's nothing glaring wrong here. You may need to urlencode $response. But not enough to help us spot your syntax error. Please post more code including the while loop you mention containing line 26.

Comment: What does echo $response return ?

Comment: Are you trying to create action.php as an intermediate between your HTML form and the existing API, or do you want to call the existing API from your HTML page?

Comment: @bitfiddler Sorry, I meant While clause (edited Q), and the code I posted was the only code in the php file. I can only assume the API is having trouble generating an ID for the database record (further explanation in a comment on one of the answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML the `name=""` part of the tag should correlate with your arg1, arg2, arg3. I don't know how much experience you have with GET and POST, but if you want the URL to contain all of the args like in your example, you should set the form method to get. The action attribute of the form tag is the page you want the values to be sent to. Try the following for your form:

```
<form action="http://mydomainname.com/folder/anotherFolder/theAPI.php" method="get">
        <div id="formtext">Name</div>
        <input type="text" name="arg1">
        <div id="formtext"><br>Email Address:</div>
        <input type="text" name="arg2"><br>
        <div id="formtext"><br>Password</div>
        <input type="text" name="arg3"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After submitting this form you should be taken to the URL `http://mydomainname.com/folder/anotherFolder/theAPI.php?arg1=inputfromfirstbox&arg2=inputfromfield2&arg3=inputfromfield3`

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. When I try your code in my project, submitting the form takes me to a page that says `30Unknown column 'ID' in 'where clause'`. Since the API I'm testing with inserts a new user into the DB, I can only assume that 'ID' refers to the UserID that is automatically generated by the server when a user is created. You don't need to add this when calling the API from iOS, though. Also, how would you go about verifying the information in the fields before the API is called? EG making sure there's no injections, etc. Or should that be done in the API? Thanks :)

Comment: For simple form validation, you could just use HTML. For example, on your email input you could use `type="email"` instead of text and `type="password"` on the password input. This would prevent the form from being submitted until that box has an @ symbol in it and would mask the password. Any kind of validation you do in HTML or Javascript can easily be bypassed, so if you want some hard validation you would be best to do it in PHP on your API.php page. As for the error you are getting on the API, it's really hard to provide any suggestions without seeing the code.

Comment: (continued) From the error you provided, it would appear that you don't have a column called ID in your database, but you are trying to use it in one of your queries on API.php. It would probably be in either an UPDATE or SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks for the 'input' tip, that was very helpful. The API I'm calling as an example is `add_user.php`. When called like `/add_user.php?name=thename&email=theemail&pass=thepass`, it would add a record into a database table called users and would automatically generate a `userID` when added. If the columns were: `ID | Name | Email | Password` then with the example above the row would be: `42 | thename | theemail | thepass`, assuming it is the 42nd user. Is it possible that the unknown ID is that ID column and it can't gen? Also, would the HTML form encode spaces into %20s and @ signs, etc? Ty

Comment: It is hard to debug the issue without knowing your database structure and the query you are using however I am fairly certain it isn't in the INSERT statement (as you don't use the WHERE clause when inserting something only when updating, selecting, or deleting). Yes the html form does encode spaces and @ symbols, but PHP will automatically convert them back to their character equivalents when you use the `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` superglobals to get the values.

Comment: I'll take them. Thanks! :p

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to put your PHP instructions between php markups.

```
<?php
 //You php script here
?>
```

Moreover, php instruction ended by ";", you did it well for $response.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];
$response = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/folder/api.php?Name=' . $name . '&Email=' . $email . '&Password=' . $password);
echo $response;
?>
```

Then, it is not a good idea to use directly data from a form. You should analyse them before (be sure that your email is a real one and not a random string etc.). To do that you can take a look at the regex : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is also helpful because it allows validation of the variables. One problem: when I submit the form it takes me to a page that says `Cannot POST /action.php`. Do I have the php file in the wrong directory? At the moment, for testing purposes, all it says is: `<?php echo 'Hello, World'; ?>`